# Legal Implications of Running a Swarm node in a VPS / Server

Tags: storage, swarm, legal

I fully support Swarm and I would like to be part of it and provide a node/farm to the Swarm network, so my questions are.

1.-While many VPS providers are fine with you running an Ethereum node many will not like the idea of unknown files being stored in one of their servers in the same way they sometimes don't like torrenting or other p2p technologies. Will running a Swarm node be as controversial for server providers as running an exit TOR node? Will they generate abuse complaints or dmca notifications that Swarm node operators would have to deal with?

2.- Currently, Storj addresses Copyright Complaints directly. https://storj.io/terms-of-use.html (See article 6). Should we expect something similar done by Swarm?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: the question has been reformulated.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking four questions (1) whether SWARM nodes are entitled to Safe Harbor under the DMCA and how they differ legally from say [TOR](https://www.law.washington.edu/Clinics/technology/Reports/TorExitNodes.pdf) or [freenet](http://www.lawtechjournal.com/articles/2002/05_021229_roemer.php)?  (2) whether it is technically possible for SWARM nodes to refuse to store or transmit certain content. (3) whether it would be possible to have some kind of whitelist/blacklist/DMCA list that nodes could optionally subscribe to. (4) whether there are any plans to implement such a system.

Comment: If the question is too broad, then it's too broad. please Mods delete the question since I cannot do it because it has answers.

Comment: @wacax still this is open ended, you are not asking a Justin good for QA format. May be you can use Reddit because they encourage these. TA.

Answer (score 2):

See number 4 in the stated objectives below (keep in mind that files are stored as chunks on multiple nodes, chunks are divided up and stored on many nodes:

chunks
pieces of data (max 4K), the basic unit of storage and retrieval in the swarm

Swarm objectives entail the following design requirements:

1) distributed storage, inclusivity, long tail of power law

2) flexible expansion of space without hardware investment decisions, unlimited growth

3) zero downtime

4) **immutable, unforgeable, verifiable yet plausibly deniable storage**

5) no single point of failure, fault and attack resilience

6) censorship resistance, universally accessible permanent public record

7) sustainability due to a incentive system

8) efficient market driven pricing. tradeable trade off of memory, persistent storage, bandwidth

9) efficient use of the blockchain by the swarm accounting protocol

10) deposit-challenge based guaranteed storage [planned for POC 0.4 by Q2 2017]

The above provided from the Swarm wiki, this information should not be considered legal advice!!!